# Charts performance

Tags: plotting, system-performance

Evaluating the following lines in my computer takes near six seconds in Mathematica 10 and near 5 in Mathematica 9.  I consider this very slow as only quantiles are being calculated from data to create this simple set of charts.  I think that Mathematica should do much better than this.  Do you agree? Thoughts?

```
data = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[RandomInteger[5], 1], 100000], {10}];
Timing@BoxWhiskerChart[data, ChartLabels -> {"a", "b", "c"}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could build your own plot function and calculate the `Quantiles` seperately as @Verbeia suggested.

Here is a little example you could expand on:

```
WhiskerChart[data_List] := Module[{n = Length[data], max, min, mean, min25, max75},
 max = Max[data];
 min = Min[data];
 mean = Quantile[data, 0.5];
 min25 = Quantile[data, 0.25];
 max75 = Quantile[data, 0.75];
 Graphics[
  {Line[{{1, min}, {1, max}}],
   Line[{{0.8, min}, {1.2, min}}],
   Line[{{0.8, max}, {1.2, max}}],
   {Orange, Rectangle[{0.7, min25}, {1.3, max75}]},
   {White, Line[{{0.7, mean}, {1.3, mean}}]}},
  Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRangePadding -> 1]
 ]

data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 1], 100000];
BoxWhiskerChart[data, AspectRatio -> 1] // Timing
WhiskerChart[data] // Timing
```

[image]

Comment: You have just created an alternate WhiskerChart that is ~15 times faster than the existing BoxWhiskerChart.  I hope that your solution doesn't escape Wolfram's radar and we get a more efficient solution in the next release of Mathematica.

Answer (score 9):

It is calculating the quantiles that takes the time. Your code takes a bit under 4 seconds on my machine in version 9, but if I cut the sample sizes to 10,000 instead of 100,000, it's just under 0.4 seconds. Clearly calculating quantiles is roughly linear in performance with respect to the sample size.

```
Table[With[{data = Table[RandomVariate[
 NormalDistribution[RandomInteger[5], 1], i], {10}]}, 
 {i, First@Timing@ BoxWhiskerChart[data, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]}], 
   {i, 20000, 120000, 20000}]

20000   0.748805
40000   1.497610
60000   2.230814
80000   2.979619
100000  3.728424
120000  4.524029
```

[image]

But note that calculating quantiles separately from the plotting function, using `Quantile`, is much faster. For the 100,000 size samples, I obtained a timing of about 0.12 seconds for the following:

```
Timing[Quantile[#, {0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9}] & /@ data]
```

So, yes, calculating quantiles in the context of `BoxWhiskerChart` does seem to be less efficient than calculating the quantiles directly. It might be something to do with the automatic outliers functionality in that charting function.